# what does the keyword 'jQuery' do in this js script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking through someone else's javascript when I came across the jQuery keyword used like this:

```
(function ($) {

    //stuff to do

})(jQuery);


jQuery(document).on('pageshow', function () {

    //call functions

});
```

what does the jQuery keyword exactly do? or am I reading this wrong and the word 'jQuery' is just an object that is returned from the script or something?

Comment: jQuery is everything but a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You are aliasing the jQuery global variable to `$` in case it was already defined.

In this case the jQuery variable represents the global variable for the jQuery library that was most likely loaded in a script tag before in the HTML code.

Comment: This mode is often used in big websites. To ensure that no script will fail when including jQuery.

Comment: so, if I wanted to call this script from another script that was also set up using this jQuery alias, how could I do that? thanks

Comment: @RDoolabh That depends on the particulars of your script, and is a separate question from your original.

Comment: You can use something like `$("#selector");` to invoke a function of the element

Comment: Without seeing the code, my guess is that you would have to copy / paste the code from one script into the other because both are anonymous functions and thus can't be called by their name.

Comment: well, when I call my function in this script, I call it by using: 'jQuery.NameOfFunction();' does the jQuery keyword again just ensure that the script wont fail as @Reflic said?

Comment: Nope, it will only ensure that no other script which possibly uses the  $ as a variable identifier will not fail.